# Dll library with images as resources. How should Uri look like?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, uri

In solution explorer to my Class Library I added folder "Resources" with few images in it (image.png).
I set build action of each image.png as "Resource".

Now inside this dll I want to return Bitmap image from those resources. But I'm getting error that file is not found.

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/de_image.png"))
```

This is error:

```
Cannot locate resource 'resources/de_image.png'.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you trying to access through a URI?

Comment: @JohnSaunders How to access it in other way?

Comment: Same as any other resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx. I've never heard of resources being accessed through a URI. What made you think that would work?

Comment: ... which would be due to the fact that I don't use WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access a resource image within XAML in a user control library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167561/how-can-i-access-a-resource-image-within-xaml-in-a-user-control-library)

Answer (score 1):

You can code like this:

`new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/[AssemblyName];component/[Path]/[To]/[Image]"))`